# Card shuffling and harmonic numbers

Tags: reference-request, permutations, systems-of-equations, harmonic-numbers, card-games

Below is a simple proof of one connection between card shuffling and [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). I'm interested in references for this if it's already known, as well as alternative methods of proof. (Can the result be obtained from the fact that the [expected number of cycles in a random $n$-permutation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/165419/16397) equals the $n$th harmonic number?)

---

For a deck of $n\ge 1$ distinct playing cards, define a *top shuffle* to be the operation of moving the top card down to one of the $n-1$ other positions, choosing this target position uniformly at random.

Let $T$ denote the number of top shuffles needed to make every card occupy the top position at least once.

> **Claim**: The expected value of $T$ is given by the following formula:
>   $$\mathbb{E}(T)=(n-1)\,\left({1\over 1}+{1\over 2}+{1\over 3}+\cdots+{1\over n-1}\right).$$

**Proof**: WLOG, represent the shuffled deck by a permutation of $(1,\ldots,n)$, the leftmost position being the "top".  Let $s_x$ denote the expected number of top shuffles needed to make card $n$ occupy the top position, given that the deck is initially the permutation $x$. Now, if the deck is initially $(1,2,..,n)$, then every card will visit the top position iff card $n$ visits the top position, so we seek $s_{1,2,..,n}=\mathbb{E}(T).$

The following system of equations is immediate from the definitions:

$$\begin{align}s_{n,1,..,n-1}&=0\\[2ex]
s_{1,n,2,3,..,n-1}&=1+{1\over n-1}\left(\underbrace{s_{n,1,2,3,..,n-1}+s_{n,2,1,3,..,n-1}+\ldots+s_{n,2,3,..,n-1,1}}_{n-1}\right)\\[2ex]
s_{1,2,n,3,..,n-1}&=1+{1\over n-1}\left(\underbrace{s_{2,1,n,3,..,n-1}}_{1}+\underbrace{s_{2,n,1,3,..,n-1}+\ldots+s_{2,n,3,..,n-1,1}}_{n-2}\right)\\[2ex]
s_{1,2,3,n,..,n-1}&=1+{1\over n-1}\left(\underbrace{s_{2,1,3,n,..,n-1}+s_{2,3,1,n,..,n-1}}_{2}+\underbrace{s_{2,3,n,1,..,n-1}+\ldots+s_{2,3,n,..,n-1,1}}_{n-3}\right)\\[2ex]
\cdots\\[2ex]
s_{1,2,3,..,n-1,n}&=1+{1\over n-1}\left(\underbrace{s_{2,1,3,..,n-1,n}+s_{2,3,1,..,n-1,n}+\ldots+s_{2,3,..,n-1,1,n}}_{n-2}+\underbrace{s_{2,3,..,n-1,n,1}}_{1}\right)\\[2ex]
\end{align}$$

Note that these $n$ equations actually involve only $n$ unknowns, due to the fact that $s_x$ *depends only on the position of $n$* in the permutation $x$. 
Therefore, let us define $t_k$ to be the expected number of top shuffles needed to make card $n$ occupy the top position, given that the deck has card $n$ in position $k$. Then we can rewrite the above system as follows:

$$\begin{cases}t_1&=0\\[2ex]
t_k&=1+{1\over n-1}\left((k-2)\,t_k+(n-k+1)\,t_{k-1}\right)\quad (k=2,..,n)\\[2ex]
\end{cases}$$ 
and hence, rearranging the equations,
$$\begin{cases}t_1&=0\\[2ex]
t_k&={n-1\over n-k+1}+t_{k-1}\quad (k=2,..,n)\\[2ex]
\end{cases}$$ 
giving
$$\begin{align}\mathbb{E}(T)=t_n&={n-1\over 1}+t_{n-1}\\[2ex]
&={n-1\over 1}+{n-1\over 2}+t_{n-2}\\[2ex]
&\cdots\\[2ex]
&={n-1\over 1}+{n-1\over 2}+\cdots+{n-1\over n-1}+t_1\\[2ex]
&=(n-1)\,\left({1\over 1}+{1\over 2}+{1\over 3}+\cdots+{1\over n-1}\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: If in the first move, the top card goes to position $2$, can't the next move undo that?

Comment: @quasi - Yes, [here](https://imgur.com/l5NYmRw)'s a picture showing the allowed transitions for $n=3.$

Comment: Your proof looks good to me (+1), but I would dispense with the part where you consider arbitrary permutations -- it's clear that the position $k$ of card $n$ is all that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is way too complicated. When card $n$ is in position $k+1$, the probability that a top shuffle moves it up to position $k$ is $\frac{n-k}{n-1}$. Thus the expected number of shuffles required to move it up from position $k+1$ to position $k$ is $\frac{n-1}{n-k}$, so the expected number of shuffles required to move it up from position $n$ to position $1$ is

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n-1}{n-k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n-1}k=(n-1)\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1k\;.
$$

You may also want to take a look at the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).