# Asymptotic number of loops in random assignment

Tags: probability, graph-theory, permutations, random-variables, random-graphs

Given *N* nodes I randomly pick a permutation of the nodes and use this permutation to define an assignment: I associate one and only one node to each node. This procedure naturally defines a graph made of loops (auto loops are allowed).

I was wondering what's the average number of loops in such a graph

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What have you tried? Linearity of expectation may be useful

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4487223/6460

Comment: This is a duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165407/name-drawing-puzzle